# setting time interval between jquery clicks event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a calculator but have not included the other operations yet where i have buttons from 0 upto 9 what i want to put the time interval between the clicks or time out between the user clicks now when user click on 1 i want to put some time here for wait and in this waited time if user click on 2 than i want the output like that 12 not 1 and 2 .please some body tell me how can i handle the another click event in click event really confuse how can i do that.I have not included my javascript because all was meaningless only including my html and css.
here is the fiddle.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zazikhan1/3Bj2A/)

```
<body>
<div class="container">    
   <div class="left"> 
     <div class="left-bottom">
        <div class="box-left">
          <div class="btnBG">
             <span>Cash Journal-Test</span>
          </div>
          <div class="btnBG">
             <span>Bank Journal-Test</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="number" data-value=""  value="" id="first" placeholder="first"/>
        <input type="number" data-value=""  value="" id="second" placeholder="last"/>
        <input type="number" data-value=""  value="" id="total" placeholder="total"/>
        <div class="box-right">            
           <div class="box-right-left" id="box-right-left">
                   <div class="btnSM">
                      <span><button data-value="1">1</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="2">2</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="3">3</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="4">4</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="5">5</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="6">6</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="7">7</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="8" value="8">8</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="9" value="9">9</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>+/-</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="0" value="0">0</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>.</span>
                  </div>
           </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure of what you are asking, but if you are looking to disable the buttons for a second after the user clicks (and you want to use jQuery) then maybe this will work for you:

```
var $total = $('#total');
var btnsDisabled = false;
$('.btnSM').on('click', function () {
    if (btnsDisabled) { return; }
    btnsDisabled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        btnsDisabled = false;
    }, 1000);
    var val = $(this).find('button').attr('data-value');
    $total.val($total.val() + val);
});
```

Comment: i only want to bind the two clicks user click on 1 than in some time he clicks on 2 i want them join like 12 .and if user click 1 and in 5 second he do not click 2 than only show me 1

Comment: Is there something specific about the behaviour resulting from my code that you want changed?

Comment: instead of disabling just i want to execute the click after some time let say i click the button and it give me the result after five second s

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea from a usability standpoint. Your user is going to think that something is broken when he or she clicks and nothing happens.

Comment: yeap but this is what user is asking from me and the other thing in this 5 second you clicked the other button than concatinate the both value and alert the result

Comment: are you getting me now

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You're probably going to need some kind of queue object to manage your queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be your solution:

```
$(".btnSM").click(function()) {
   var val = $(this).children().find('button').val();
   $('#total').text(val);
   setTimeout($(".btnSM").click() , 1000); }
```

I am not too sure if this will work or not.

Comment: bro what about the second click

Comment: I think that adding the value to the total textbox should work and if you hit two button say 1 and 2 the value in the totals textbox would be 12

Comment: than we will need a trigger to fire another event automatically

Comment: Why would you need another trigger?

Comment: only to popup the alert

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to have timeout between clicks?

I think just appending the number that user click is enough for calculator.

```
$(".btnSM").on('click', function() {
    var val = "" + $('#total').val() + $(this).find('button').text();
    $('#total').val(val);
});
```

Comment: ok let i have some element in cart and the element price is 700$ and user want to the same element in 12 quantity that user can select from this calculator